# BeautifulSoup - find_all .text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to work with BeautifulSoup

```
for tag in soup.find_all('td', 
    attrs= {'class': "txtd hidden-phone mobile-f12 stack-mobile"}):
    print(tag)
```

And the output is

```
<td class="txtd hidden-phone mobile-f12 stack-mobile"><a href="/btc/address/16P54KtKHTgkc9d4UQFZf81iv99z41mCsn">16P54KtKHTgkc9d4UQFZf81iv99z41mCsn</a><br/><a href="/btc/address/13ApArvHxx1ATNZ3AtMbvi7AB3MbT1nns9">13ApArvHxx1ATNZ3AtMbvi7AB3MbT1nns9</a><br/></td>
```

UPD: `print(tag.text)` gives me a full text but with no spaces, how do I split it?

Comment: You asked for all tags with a specific attribute, and you got them. What exactly confuses you?

Comment: I edited a question a little bit, now it doesn't confuse me

Answer (score 0):

[16P54KtKHTgkc9d4UQFZf81iv99z41mCsn](/btc/address/16P54KtKHTgkc9d4UQFZf81iv99z41mCsn)



[13ApArvHxx1ATNZ3AtMbvi7AB3MbT1nns9](/btc/address/13ApArvHxx1ATNZ3AtMbvi7AB3MbT1nns9)

Have you tried iterating over tags.text

something like,

```
for text_value in tags.text:
    print(text_value)
```

Comment: I just get a 1 symbol in each line. Actually, tag.text gives me a full text but with no spaces, I must have missed that

Comment: most bitcoin addresses are 34 char's long? if that's the case with yours, then you can split the whole text in 2 string of 34 chars each?

Comment: Yeah I thought about it, but some of they can be 27-34 as well

Comment: aah, have you tried iterating over the <a tag's in the tag that you get. I mean you have 2 a tags in the <td>

like this,

<a href="/btc/address/16P54KtKHTgkc9d4UQFZf81iv99z41mCsn">16P54KtKHTgkc9d4UQFZf81iv99z41mCsn</a><br/><a href="/btc/address/13ApArvHxx1ATNZ3AtMbvi7AB3MbT1nns9">13ApArvHxx1ATNZ3AtMbvi7AB3MbT1nns9</a><br/>

Comment: I don't think I have, how can I do that?

Comment: I may be wrong with this one, but try using, print(tag.get_text(separator=' '))
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `.text` (which is a concatenation of all strings in the tag). You need `.strings`:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('td', 
    attrs= {'class': "txtd hidden-phone mobile-f12 stack-mobile"}):
    print(list(tag.strings))
```